# Set background color for all inner td inside div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I need to set background color for all inner td inside div.

I was used:

```
$('#'+div_id).find('table').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').css('background-color','color');
```

But this was not working for me.

Comment: Also you can replace `$('#'+div_id).find('table').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td')` to `$('#'+div_id+' table tbody tr td')`

Comment: You know, `.find()` can find *any* descendant, not just an immediate one.

Comment: seems to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/wdbat3kn/

Comment: is `color` Your variable? so You chould do: `$('#'+div_id).find('table').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').css('background-color',color);` no quotes around variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a color.

'color' is not a valid color, so change that to either a variable or a color:

```js
var div_id = 'div'
var color = 'red'

$('#' + div_id).find('table').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').css('background-color', color);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I assigned color name as another value.But not working for me.

Comment: @Thirupathi You said `'color'` (a string) but you need something like `'red'` (a valid color in a string) or a variable of a color. See my edit. You need to get rid of the quotes and use the `color` variable

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#'+div_id + 'table tr td').css('background-color','blue');
```

also, check if it's not overridden by other css styles

Comment: You could even reduce it to `$('#'+div_id+' td')` but it doesn’t solve the problem of the `'color'` string.

Comment: maybe, it's overridden by other css styles

Comment: Possible, but as it your answer sets the `background-color` to the color `'color'`, which isn’t a valid CSS color. The original question probably assumed that there was a `var color` being set somewhere.

Comment: I knew that, I just didn't want to specify name of the color!

Answer (score 0):

Should be :

```
$('#'+div_id).find('td').css({'background-color':'Red'});
```